# Cannot install Git on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, git

When I was trying to install Git on Ubuntu 16.04, I get an error. The command I used to install git is:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

The error I encountered was:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: git-man (> 1:2.7.4) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: git-man (< 1:2.7.4-.) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or
specify a solution).
```

Even though I used the suggested command (apt-get -f install) to install git the error still persists. Anyone who has the idea to fix this problem?

Comment: yes, I ran it but the problem still persists

Comment: Please try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get -f install`

Comment: Already tried, same error encountered

Comment: Lets see if `gdebi` will help: `sudo apt-get install gdebi && sudo gdebi git`

Comment: The previous solution (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get -f install) worked, I just had the 3 commands ran one by one. Thanks for the help

Comment: One down one more to go, glad it worked! Will be including answer for you to accept...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some times our systems may not be up-to-date to receive an install so we can update with:

- update package information:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- upgrade packages on system *and* fix broken packages in the process:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
  ```
- *only* fix broken packages:

  ```
  sudo apt-get -f install
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with `liberror-perl` when trying to install `git`. The other answers (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get -f install`) didn't work for me.

From manually following the chain of dependency problems by trying to install each package directly, it looks like the problem is with `perl-base`:

```
$ sudo apt install liberror-perl
  liberror-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed

$ sudo apt install perl
  perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.22.1-9) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 is to be installed

$ sudo apt install perl-base
  perl-base is already the newest version (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5).
```

So the `perl` package depends on an outdated version of perl-base. I'm not sure how that was caused, but I suspect at one point a newer version was available, perhaps from a temporary apt source that was later removed on my system. I fixed the problem by downgrading `perl-base` to the version `perl` wants:

```
$ sudo apt install -f perl-base=5.22.1-9
```

After that, git installs properly. Just in case there was a newer perl-base version available, I tried upgrading it, but the above version was also the latest version:

```
$ sudo apt install perl-base=\*
perl-base is already the newest version (5.22.1-9).
Selected version '5.22.1-9' (Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64]) for 'perl-base'
```

As far as I know this should not cause any problems, but YMMV.