# How to solve error installing Git on 16.04 LTS

Tags: gitlab

sudo apt-get install git-all

results in this output:

```
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcommon-sense-perl (3.74-1build1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up libtypes-serialiser-perl (1.0-1) ...
Setting up libjson-xs-perl (3.010-2build1) ...
Setting up libpackage-stash-xs-perl (0.28-2build2) ...
Setting up tla-doc (1.3.5+dfsg1-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu13) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I saw [the other similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886765/cannot-install-git-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts), and performed these steps,

```
sudo apt-get update --> update package information
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --> upgrade packages on system
sudo apt-get -f install --> fix broken packages
```

but it did not solve the issue.  The git install also causes the "System Program Problem Detected" popup.  This is followed by "Crash Report = Sorry a problem occurred while installing software. Package: runit 2.1.2-3ubuntu1.

Comment: I had the exact issue a few minutes ago. I found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771839/problem-installing-package-git-all/771889#771889

Answer (score 0):

After further searching and experimenting, I found [this procedure](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2334659&p=13534248#post13534248) that fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge runit
sudo apt-get purge git-all
sudo apt-get purge git
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```