# Error while installing git

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, git

I am trying to install git on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but every time I get this message. I have already uninstalled libpcre2-8-0, and synaptic shows nothing in broken packages. It shows only when I mark git-core package to install, and I don't know what to do after.

```
$ sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.22) but 10.21-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to put in the output of apt policy libpcre.

Comment: See if this is any help: [Cannot install Git on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/886765/301745)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution use synaptic.

What you could try

```
sudo apt install libpcre2-8-0
```

Otherwise get synaptic if possible and try to install git through it. It's a front end application for apt. Try to install it with apt. If issues occur, get the packages from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/

```
dpkg -i ~/Downloads/'package name'
```

This will also give you the output if you need anything else.

Comment: Thank you man, downloading the packages and dpking works here

Comment: Awesome glad I could help you. :)